# #value error with excel user defined function

Tags: excel, vba

I have created user defined function in excel VBA:

```
Public Function RegExpReplace(Text As String, Pattern As String, replaceVar As String, Optional Glob As Boolean = False, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False, Optional Multiline As Boolean = False) As Variant
On Error GoTo ErrHandl
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.Pattern = Pattern
regex.Global = Glob
regex.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
regex.Multiline = Multiline
RegExpReplace = CVar(regex.Replace(Text, replaceVar))
MsgBox RegExpReplace
ErrHandl:
RegExpReplace = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

But when I am trying to call it from sheet i got **#VALUE!** error:

[image: error screenshot (localized excel)]

while MsgBox shows correct result:

[image: MsgBox screenshot]

Comment: The code you posted is working for me. But as you did not post the whole code it's difficult to tell what your issue is. Especially there is no error handling code posted. I guess you also run through this code although the function was completed successfully.

Comment: Call your function from a VBA Sub and you can debug more easily.

Comment: @Storax This is hole code. The purpose was to add this function to excel  Add-in (. xlam file) and use it on worksheets.

Comment: If this is the whole code you get a compile error and you will not get a MsgBox giving you the result you showed. Every function needs to end with a `End Function` and you alse need to define the label `ErrHandl`. Please check your code again more carefully.

Comment: @Storax Thank you, i just forget to post last 3 lines of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like that

```
Public Function RegExpReplace(Text As String, Pattern As String, replaceVar As String, Optional Glob As Boolean = False, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False, Optional Multiline As Boolean = False) As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = Pattern
    regex.Global = Glob
    regex.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    regex.Multiline = Multiline
    RegExpReplace = CVar(regex.Replace(Text, replaceVar))
    MsgBox RegExpReplace
    Exit Function
ErrHandl:
    RegExpReplace = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

You forgot to exit the function in case there is no error and because of that the line `RegExpReplace = CVErr(xlErrValue)` was also executed giving you *#Value* even if there is no error.